# How can I reconnect Selenium to IE11 after navigating with the prerender resource hint?

Tags: ruby, selenium, internet-explorer-11, saucelabs

I'm working on a Selenium (Ruby API) test that navigates from one page to another.  It started failing on IE11/Win10 (via SauceLabs) recently when I added a [`link rel="prerender"`](https://www.w3.org/TR/resource-hints/#prerender) resource hint on the first page pointing to the second page, to speed up navigation.  The failure is this ([see full backtrace](https://gist.github.com/islemaster/10c5aab03df5d07789f604786ef9456e)) and consistently occurs on the first Selenium command after navigation occurs.

```
Unable to find element on closed window (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 4 milliseconds
Build info: version: '2.53.1', revision: 'a36b8b1', time: '2016-06-30 17:37:03'
System info: host: 'WIN-SB3ER6JQ6ME', ip: '172.20.114.237', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'x86', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_91'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.ie.InternetExplorerDriver
Capabilities [{browserAttachTimeout=0, ie.enableFullPageScreenshot=true, enablePersistentHover=false, ie.forceCreateProcessApi=false, ie.forceShellWindowsApi=false, pageLoadStrategy=normal, ignoreZoomSetting=false, ie.fileUploadDialogTimeout=3000, version=11, platform=WINDOWS, nativeEvents=false, ie.ensureCleanSession=false, elementScrollBehavior=0, ie.browserCommandLineSwitches=, requireWindowFocus=false, browserName=internet explorer, initialBrowserUrl=about:blank, javascriptEnabled=true, ignoreProtectedModeSettings=false, enableElementCacheCleanup=true, unexpectedAlertBehaviour=dismiss}]
Session ID: XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX79d496ee
*** Element info: {Using=class name, value=dialog-title} (org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchWindowException) (Selenium::WebDriver::Error::NoSuchWindowError)
```

For what it's worth, the prerendering works fine when testing IE11 manually, and Selenium+Chrome (which also respects the prerender directive) has no problem with this.

My *suspicion* is that IE implements the prerender by loading the page in a hidden window/context, then destroying the current window and swapping in the new one upon navigation - causing Selenium's handle on the window to become invalid.  I've already attempted to work around this by trying to force Selenium to reconnect to the window:

```
# Wait a few seconds, then
@driver.switch_to.window(@driver.window_handles.last)
```

But I've discovered that `@driver.window_handles` is empty after navigation, even though the SauceLabs screencast shows the navigation working properly.

Is there any way to reconnect Selenium to IE11 after navigating with the prerender resource hint?

Comment: Cross-posted to the [selenium-users group](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/selenium-users).

Comment: Here's the [selenium-users group post](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/selenium-users/bUuOue_7p0o) (now approved so I can link to it).  No help there yet, though.